# AWS RDS Aurora Free Disk Space Metric

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-aurora

I just upgraded a database to use aurora and am trying to set up a cloudwatch alarm if the total aurora cluster free space drops below a certain level.

According to the Aurora docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html there should be a metric called `AuroraVolumeBytesLeftTotal` but I can't find it anywhere in cloudwatch.

I am using MYSQL version 5.6 so I think it is the first version of Aurora the database is using. Is this a metric that was added to the second version of Aurora?

Does anyone know how I can get a metric for free space?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html, it looks like metrics don't show up unless there is enough data available:

> Metrics that have not had any new data points in the past two weeks do not appear in the console. They also do not appear when you type their metric name or dimension names in the search box in the All metrics tab in the console, and they are not returned in the results of a list-metrics command. The best way to retrieve these metrics is with the get-metric-data or get-metric-statistics commands in the AWS CLI.
>
> If the old metric you want to view has a current metric with similar dimensions, you can view that current similar metric and then choose the Source tab, and change the metric name and dimension fields to the ones that you want, and also change the time range to a time when the metric was being reported.